# Что делать, если не работает игра сделанная на Unity с WebGL для Яндекс игр?

Tags: unity3d

Проблема в том, что игра запускается, показывает логотип Unity, но затем появляется ошибка, как на скрине ниже и всё останавливается.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]